# React Native: Create Diagram and Graph view for React Native app

Tags: react-native, mobile, diagram

I have a project that need to create a diagram view on mobile app. I've researched some libs but still cannot to find any solution. Anyone know some good library run on react native? please help to let me know, thank in advance!

Comment: Diagram and graph are ambiguous terms. Are you looking for bar-charts or node-edge-diagrams?

Comment: Graphics support for react-native is very poor, especially for interactive graphics. This is due to the platform abstraction and the missing low-level graphics layer. Hence it will be hard to find anything that is non-static.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, thank for your help. I'm looking for node-edge-diagrams. Do you know is there any libs for react native that can create diagram like JointJS

Answer (score 0):

I found this library

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg-charts
```

First, install this library

```
npm i react-native-svg-charts
npm i react-native-svg
```

Second

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Create new screen like this,

```
import React from 'react';
import {BarChart, XAxis} from 'react-native-svg-charts';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import * as scale from 'd3-scale';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const data = [14, 80, 100, 55];

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            height: 200,
            width: '80%',
          }}>
          <BarChart
            style={{flex: 1}}
            data={data}
            gridMin={0}
            svg={{fill: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)'}}
          />
          <XAxis
            style={{marginTop: 10}}
            data={data}
            scale={scale.scaleBand}
            formatLabel={(value, index) => index}
            labelStyle={{color: 'black'}}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check these lists to find the most suitable for you:

- [Top 8 at logRocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-top-8-react-native-chart-libraries-for-2021/)
- [Top 12 at rlogical](https://www.rlogical.com/blog/12-great-react-native-chart-libraries-to-use-in-2021/)